# SQLite Insert Row gets automatically removed

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I'm inserting data into SQLIte database in WPF Visual C#. The insert command works fine. I check the function by returning the total number of rows in result and it shows the row is inserted. However when I check for all the data, it shows nothing. Also I tried getting total count and it shows 0.

Here is the code of my Database Controller:

```
class TableController
{
    SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;

    public TableController()
    {
        SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("MyDatabase.sqlite");
        m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
        createDb();

    }

    public void createDb()
    {

        m_dbConnection.Open();
        string sql = "CREATE TABLE data (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR(50), address VARCHAR(100), mobile VARCHAR(20), date VARCHAR(20), price VARCHAR(20), warranty VARCHAR(20), month VARCHAR(20))";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        m_dbConnection.Close();
    }

    public Boolean add_data(Objectdata od)
    {
            m_dbConnection.Open();
            string sql = "INSERT INTO data (name, address, mobile, date, price, warranty, month) values ('" + od.name + "', '" + od.address + "', '" + od.mobile + "', '" + od.date + "', '" + od.price + "', '" + od.warranty + "', '" + od.month + "')";
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
            int a = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            m_dbConnection.Close();

            if (a == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if (a == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

    }


    public List<Objectdata> getAllData()
    {

        m_dbConnection.Open();
        List<Objectdata> dataList = new List<Objectdata>();
        Objectdata oD = new Objectdata();

        string sql = "select * from data order by id";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            oD.setId(reader["id"].ToString());
            oD.setName(reader["name"].ToString());
            oD.setAddress(reader["address"].ToString());
            oD.setMobile(reader["mobile"].ToString());
            oD.setDate(reader["date"].ToString());
            oD.setPrice(reader["price"].ToString());
            oD.setWarranty(reader["warranty"].ToString());
            oD.setMonth(reader["month"].ToString());

            dataList.Add(oD);

        }
        m_dbConnection.Close();


        return dataList;
    }

    public Objectdata getSingleData(String id)
    {

        m_dbConnection.Open();

        Objectdata oD = new Objectdata();

        string sql = "select * from data WHERE id = '" + id + "'";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            oD.setId(reader["id"]);
            oD.setName(reader["name"]);
            oD.setAddress(reader["address"]);
            oD.setDate(reader["date"]);
            oD.setMobile(reader["mobile"]);
            oD.setPrice(reader["price"]);
            oD.setWarranty(reader["warranty"]);

        }
        m_dbConnection.Close();

        return oD;

    }

    public int getCount()
    {

        m_dbConnection.Open();

        int count = 0;
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM data";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            count++;
        }
        m_dbConnection.Close();
        return count;
    }
```

And I'm accessing the data through this class.

```
 TableController tablecon = new TableController();

            Objectdata ob = new Objectdata();
            ob.name = name.Text.ToString();
            ob.address = address.Text.ToString();
            ob.mobile = mobile.Text.ToString();
            ob.date = date.Text.ToString();
            ob.price = price.Text.ToString();
            ob.warranty = warranty.Text.ToString();
            ob.month = mc.returnMonth(date.Text.ToString());
            Boolean res = tablecon.add_data(ob);

            if (res)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Added");
                name.Clear();
                name.Clear();
                address.Clear();
                mobile.Clear();
                price.Clear();
                warranty.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry an error occurred!");
            }

      private void button_refresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TableController a = new TableController();
        dataList = a.getAllData();
        listView.ItemsSource = dataList;
    }
```

And one of the class to check the count ( it shows zero ):

```
 public void getId(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
        load_data(id);
    }

    public void load_data(String id)
    {
        Objectdata o = new Objectdata();
        o = tableContoller.getSingleData(id);
        name.AppendText(tableContoller.getCount().ToString());
        address.AppendText(o.getAddress());
        mobile.AppendText(o.getMobile());
        date.AppendText(o.getDate());
        price.AppendText(o.getPrice());
        warranty.AppendText(o.getWarranty());
    }
```

Comment: Pretty sure its because you create the connection in your constructor. You should create the connection, open the connection, do whatever, then close the connection immediately after. Also, you need to wrap your connection and your commands in `using` blocks so that the connection can be disposed properly.

Comment: So I have to put           m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");            in individual function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CreateDB()` method is confusing cause it's will try re-creating the table `data` which actually should throw an exception. By any means, remove that method call from constructor. see your constructor ...

```
   public TableController()
    {
        SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("MyDatabase.sqlite");
        m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
        createDb(); <-- this line

    }
```

Comment: So, if the table exists that command destroys the old table and create a new one? It seems pretty odd for the CREATE TABLE command to do that. Surely I have not seen this behavior in other databases.

Comment: @Steve, Hmm yes that's not the case but per his code ... it should throw an error as well; I mean the code shouldn't run in first place.

Comment: So how should I get this done? I'm not very sure, but it had worked before. I have lost my earlier code and couldn't remember how I did it. Maybe I should create a table only once just to check and then try performing queries.

Comment: @BasuSingh, your createDB() method is confusing and it should actually throw an exception. But by any means remove that method call from constructor. create your table once in Sqlite

Comment: I made a few change: removed createDB() from constructure and then tried the function from a button click but it throws an error. How can I create the table in Sqlite? Don't have much idea. Moved from Android to Windows.

Comment: @BasuSingh, you are getting error cause the table already created and so you don't have to create it again. See Sqlite documentation on creating table https://www.sqlite.org/

Comment: @BasuSingh, consider accepting the answer if it helped.

Comment: Thanks for help. I made this working by checking for existence of table.